# How to set up labels in google dataflow jobs using scio?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow, spotify-scio

I want to set up labels for google dataflow jobs for cost allocation purpose. Here is an example of working Java Code:

```
private DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).as(DataflowPipelineOptionsImpl.class); 
options.setLabels(ImmutableMap.of("key", "value"));
```

setLabels: [Method Documentation Link](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/options/DataflowPipelineOptions.html#setLabels-java.util.Map-)

Can someone please help with scio / scala example ? I checked few scio + google dataflow examples but I couldn't find anything helpful.

Other option is provide label argument in mvn / gradle command like below:

> ```
>       mvn compile exec:java   
>      --Dexec.mainClass=com.example.WordCount   -Dexec.args="--project=test-prod \
>      --stagingLocation=gs://test-bucket/staging/ \
>      --output=gs://test-bucket/output \
>      --runner=TestDataflowPipelineRunner \
>      --labels=\"{'a':'b'}\" \
>      --jobName=dataflow-intro"
> ```

I am not sure if passing labels={a:b} is the correct syntax.

Any help? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In scio you can do:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val (sc: ScioContext, args: Args) = ContextAndArgs(cmdLineArgs)
sc.optionsAs[DataflowPipelineOptions].setLabels(Map("foo" -> "bar").asJava)
```

From the command line you can pass the labels param as a json string, e.g.:

```
mvn compile exec:java \
--Dexec.mainClass=com.example.WordCount \
--labels={"a":"b"} \
...
```